# Perforce: integrate output syntax

Tags: perforce

I have a java application which takes a branchspec name and use

```
p4 integrate -b <branchSpec>
```

command to do the integration.
I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() for this purpose.

Everything was working fine till one day I got problem due to an integration. After investigating, I found out that perforce is masking a error "can't branch exclusive files" and that's why I could not get it as an error (the process is returning error code 0).

I don't know how many such errors perforce is masking. To overcome this problem, I decided to check each output line such that it should match the output syntax.

But I couldn't find out what is the output syntax of **'p4 integrate'**.
It is not given in Perforce documentation of Integrate command either.

What I could manage to get by some experiments is:

```
<destination_fileSpec>-[(branch/sync)(integrate)(delete)] from <source_fileSpec>
```

Is anything missing?

Comment: It is not defined in documentation, however I cannot recall it changing recently. Whenever I've had to parse P4 output, I've done exactly what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the P4Java API, which can run any Perforce command and provides much cleaner error handling.